# Capacitance of a particular transmission line

Tags: capacitance, transmission-line, homework

Is it possible to derive the expressione of the equivalent capacitance seen by *AB* for this kind of transmission line, where *w* is the width of the wire, *d* the spacing, *l* the length of the repeated part and *n* the number of meanders?

[image]

I know that for a typical transmission line without this meander part, the capacitance per unit length is given by

$$
c=\frac{\pi\epsilon}{log(d/w)}
$$

Now in this case, as a first approximation, I can calculate the capacitance between the first neighbors and than add them in series. Is this correct? Or should I also take in consideration the second neighbors and so on? How can I add them?

Edit: to simplify the problem, you can consider *l* big, so that you can neglect the effect of the corners and of the connection between one segment and the other. You can also assume *w << d*, if this can help.

Comment: Are you asking about the capacitance from the line to a plane underneath or something else?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson:what I'm looking for is the capacitance among the segments of length _l_

Comment: Coplanar capacitance is defined by 3D geometry just like but different over a ground plane. But since they are not insulated the, inductance over-rides impedance (corners shunt capacitance) except for a small resonance to free space or substrate . What result due you want ? SRF? Or Z(f)

Comment: @TonyStewartolderthandirt: probably I don't have enough knowledge to fully understand your remark. Anyway, what I'm looking for is the geometric expression of the capacitance per unit length.

Comment: The thickness of your lines will matter, won't it? Oh, and engineers use italic capital \$C\$ to represent capacitance. Lowercase upright c is a constant, the speed of light in a vacuum.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson: you can consider the wire with a circular cross section. With _c_ I mean the capacitance per unit length.

Comment: Andrea get free Saturn PCB software and explore it . It won’t give a better answer here because a capacitor has more than a single conductor but you can see the capacitance of two adjacent opposing track variables , inductance , impedance and fast learn how to make 50 Ohms. Your simplified formula applies to depth, d to an ground plane

Comment: The *d* and *w* in your equation represent different dimensions than they do in your drawing.

Comment: @ThePhoton: I miswrote the factor of 2, thanks, but what's the problem with _w_ and _d_? You mean that _d_ should be the distance between the center of the two wires instead of the spacing?

Comment: If I read the question properly, you might want to look up the term "equivalent parallel capacitance" in the context of inductors.

Comment: @Felthry: The one on the left is not a coil but of course can be seen as a wire inductor in a meander format, so yes your interpretation is correct. Any idea?